# CPanel and sending Email from Python SMTP

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtp, cpanel, smtplib

I found  a system hosted on CPanel. However I have a service running on another server written in Python. This python service is what will send emails however the domain name testservice.com is on CPanel including the mail exhange.

CPanel gives me the configurations for SMTP to be

`SMTP servver: mail.testservice.com PORT: 465, uername: usr@testservice.com,`

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mail.testservice.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login("usr@testservice.com", 'xxxx')
    server.sendmail('usr@testservice.com', 'rec@gmail.com', 'hello world')
```

I'm currently testing this on my local host and I get the following error:

```
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'Your FROM address ( testservice.com ,  ) must match your\nauthenticated email domain ( testservice.com ). Treating this as a\nspoofed email.')
```